# VBScript - Take an IP Address and Reverse it

Tags: vbscript, ip

Very little experience with VB and running into a headache.
I need to take an IP and reverse it.

For example - 11.22.33.44 would become 44.33.22.11

I'm guessing reverse the whole lot then split and reverse each section based on . delimiter

Strictly speaking what i'm trying to do is reverse the order of the octets - 192.168.42.23 should become 23.42.168.192

Thanks

EDIT - Clarification

Comment: VB.NET and VBScript are different, please specify which one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split the IP address into its octets and recombine them in reversed order:

```
addr1 = Split("11.22.33.44", ".")
maxindex = UBound(addr1)
ReDim addr2(maxindex)
For i = 0 To maxindex
  addr2(maxindex - i) = addr1(i)
Next

WScript.Echo "Forward: " & Join(addr1, ".")
WScript.Echo "Reverse: " & Join(addr2, ".")
```

Output:

```
Forward: 11.22.33.44
Reverse: 44.33.22.11
```

Answer (score 2):

For your example, string reverse will do the trick.

```
Dim txt
txt="This is a beautiful day!"
document.write(StrReverse(txt))

Output:

!yad lufituaeb a si sihT
```

That will only work for the example you provided. If you need to reverse this:
12.34.56.78, the above will return 87.65.43.21 but you want 78.56.34.12.

Then combine split + loop:

```
    a=Split("11.22.33.44", ".", 4)
    b= a(0)
    For i = 1 To 3
      b = a(i) & "." & b
    Next
    WScript.Echo  b
```

UPDATE:
Or no loop at all!

```
    a=Split("11.22.33.44", ".", 4)
    b= a(3) & "." & a(2) & "." & a(1) & "." & a(0)
    WScript.Echo  b
```

Comment: thanks - im getting unexpected end of statement at   b = b & "." & a[i]

Comment: wrong array index parens: [] ==> ()); the index of 44 is 3, the result will start with a .!

Comment: Right. Cannot loop backwards. Updated and tested this one.

Comment: @Jonathan Of course you can loop backwards. You just need a negative step value: `For i = 3 To 1 Step -1`